# Vagrant ssh : Puttygen can't generate ssh-2rsa key in Windows

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, vagrant, private-key

I am trying to build a linux server with vagrant in Windows 8.1 but it fails to ssh so I tried to set up ssh connection with putty by following the instruction here: http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/01/25/how-to-use-vagrant-on-windows.html

The main problem is I can't generate key in ssh2-rsa format coz the puttygen in my environment doesn't even hv the ssh2-rsa format option for the conversion of key format. It only has ssh-1rsa for me to choose. I tried this out but the connection is aborted immediately after I open the connection in putty with the ssh-1rsa key.

How come and what else can I do?

Also, what is the appropriate setting for network adaptor for vagrant ssh in virtualbox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. I guess newer versions of putty has different parameters. RSA itself is SSH-2 RSA. Check under "Key" menu